# creating IEnumerable[] without knowing the type at compile time

Tags: c#

I am in a situation that i have to create an instance without knowing the type at compile time.

My code is liket this:

```
     IEnumerable[] columns = new IEnumerable[5]; 

     columns[0] = new string[]{};
```

i have to be able to create colums[0] without knowing the type ( which is string in the above example).

I couldn't find a solution to my problem, any suggestion is welcomed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: look up generic types.

Comment: Why don't you use `System.Object`, which is the parent of all classes?

Comment: @ChristophKn That and `dynamic` are like using rocket launchers to kill a fly. You'd cause way more damage than good. As was already mentioned, generics are the way to go.

Comment: You really should consider a different approach, it seems like you design has some weakness.

Comment: @dh_cgn how is that ? in fact i have something like this :
columns[0] = new string[] { "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b" };
and i don't want it to be static i want to be able to determine the type and add elements at runtime

Comment: `new IEnumerable[5];` this is impossible. You can't create an instance of an interface; only a type that implements an interface. `IEnumerable[] columns = new List<...>() ` would work because the `List` type implements `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics like this:

```
class MyBusiness<T> where T: new()
{
    public List<T> coll { get; set; }

    public MyBusiness(){
        coll = new List<T>();
    }

    public void DoSth(){
        T t = new T();
        coll.Add(t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take a look into [Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/512aeb7t.aspx). They allow you to create a class that doesn't need to know what the type is until you use it.

```
public class Column<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
}
```

So you'd use it in your program like so:

```
var columns = new IEnumerable<Column<string>>();
```